# Problem while sending file between 2 servers

Tags: javascript, server, encoding, fetch, multipartform-data

I want to send a file from a server to an other.
The problem is that my second server (who receive) don't read correctly my file.
Normally I send my file to an API but I create a little server to make my own tests.

My server (sender):

First I got my file with `multer().single('file')`
(My file only contain "Hello")

```
const formData = new FormData();
    const file = new File(req.file.buffer, req.file.originalname, { type: req.file.mimetype })
    formData.append("file", file);

    let firstFile = null;
    for (const [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
        if (value instanceof File) {
            firstFile = value;
            break;
        }
    }

    const uploadres = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        body: firstFile
    })
```

Then I read the file like this :

```
var body;

    body = '';
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log(req.method + ' ' + req.url + ' HTTP/' + req.httpVersion);

        for (prop in req.headers) {
            console.log(toTitleCase(prop) + ': ' + req.headers[prop]);
        }

        if (body.length > 0) {
            if (req.headers['content-type'] === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
                body = decodeURIComponent(body)
            }
            console.log('\n' + body);
        }
        console.log('');

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
    });
```

my server print: "72101108108111"

I know that something was wrong in my code because the API receive my file but don't doesn't perform normally.

I think my problem become from encoding but I don't know how to fix that.

I have try a lot of things, like change my file with another etc. but nothing works.

Comment: You are using Content-Type as multipart in the sender, but then checking if the content-type is form-urlencoded in the reciever. That seems odd to me.

Comment: Please limit the code to the parts actually needed to understand the issue--it's not clear if the mis-matched content-types are related or not. It's also not clear which of the console logs is actually printing the digits.

Comment: @tutiplain the server who receive is given by the other dev in my company, I'm new in web im doing an internship, so I trust their files ^^'

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry I'm new in webdev so I don't really understand what is important and what is not. Mb

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "72101108108111" is the decimal representation of the ASCII encoding of the characters "Hello".

It might help to update the second code snippet to parse the data as a binary buffer instead of a string.

replace `body = '';` with `let body = []`

replace `body += chunk` with `body.push(chunk)`

add `body = Buffer.concat(body)` to the first line of the `.on('end'` callback

and then use the `.toString()` to see the result

```
if (body.length > 0) {
  console.log(body.toString('utf-8'));
}
```

Comment: I have try your modification that give me the same "72101108108111"
I don't think it's an ascii number because if I try to translate it, that doesn't work

Comment: @Baku https://www.asciitable.com/ Pretty sure it is: H = 72, e = 101, l = 108, o = 111.

Comment: Oh yeah, mb on this. Do you know how can I not send that in ASCII but without modification ? Because later I have to send not only txt file but img/pdf etc